# Contact us form action not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

Not sure why this isn't working, but I suspect it's something to do with routing... (Using MVC5)

When clicking on the submit button I get the following message:
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /contact

Using a model as follows:

```
public class EmailMessageModel
{
    /// <summary>Gets or sets from name.</summary>
    /// <value>From name.</value>
    [Required, Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string FromName { get; set; }
}
```

The view is then as follows:

```
@model EmailMessageModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "contact", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "contact-form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)

    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="btnSubmitQuery" />
}
```

Controller is as follows:

**(the breakpoint on the HttpPost Index action is never hit, any ideas why?)**

namespace ExternalSite.Controllers
{
    using ExternalSite.Models;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

```
[RoutePrefix("contact")]
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailMessageModel model)
    {
        // !!!!!!!!!!BREAKPOINT HERE IS NEVER BEING HIT!!!!!!!!!!!
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the blank route attribute [Route] to the HttpPost Index method, i.e.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailMessageModel model)
{
    // !!!!!!!!!!BREAKPOINT HERE IS NEVER BEING HIT!!!!!!!!!!!
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }

    return View(model);
}
```